# Upload and Submit Resume feature for Drupal 7

Tags: file, drupal, upload

I am creating a job website using Drupal 7. I have a job listings content type and I want anonymous users to be able to upload and submit resumes to the specific author that has created the job listing. I just want to know what would be the best way to implement this feature.

Example: Employer A signs up and sets up a job for an Assistant Manager using the job listing content type. An anonymous user is then able to view the Assistant Manager and submit a resume on that page that sends it to the author.

Answer (score 0):

Try webforms in drupal its easy to implement and will do as per what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have created a webform block now and I am trying to use a token to have the default value be the author of the node but I'm not sure which token to use or if that is even possible. Here is a link of what I mean [link](http://rexlaw.webfactional.com/help.jpg). I want the default value be the email of the author of the node. Any help is appreciated since I am new to Drupal 7 and am still figuring things out. Thanks.

Comment: I think its %author-mail.  I am not sure. Also here is a list just below the default input field called 'tokens' you can see which one will suit you

Comment: No I was not. I decided to use the privatemsg module instead which is a little different but works for what I need the site to do.